# crear un .exe en python que muestre salida por consola

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un fichero que se llama prueba.py
La unica instruccion de ese fichero es print("hola")
Cuando genero el exe con cxfreeze al ejecutar dicho exe no ocurre nada.
lo genero con este comando C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\cxfreeze.exe --base-name=Win32GUI prueba.py
Con cxfreeze lo uso habitualmente para hacer exe de ficheros con interfaz grafica y si funciona bien.
Me gustaria saber como hacer para poder generar un .exe  que me muestre esa salida por pantalla.
Gracias

Comment: ¿Lo ejecutas desde una ventana de terminal o simplemente pinchas un icono?

Comment: Simplemente pincho un icono.

Comment: El exe que tienes es una aplicación de consola; no es una aplicación gráfica. Necesita ser ejecutado dentro de una consola o terminal.

Comment: EL caso es que cuando lo ejecuto desde consola el resultado es el mismo.  No me printa el "hola".